# Firebase auth is null when querying firestore despite being signed in

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

I'm using the Web / JS SDK with Firebase auth to authenticate users (using phone number), then trying to create a Firestore document (also using the Web SDK) with security rules in place.  But despite being authenticated, every security rule fails because the request auth is null for some reason.  In the example below, I am trying to create a document whose ID is equal to the authenticated user's uid (generated by Firebase).  The uid in this case is `pbc5l8cca7ELtwM0Kxctn9xLeT2i` (it's visible in the debug logging).

My rules:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    // Allow only authenticated content owners access
    match /preferences/{userId} {
        allow read, update: if debug(request.auth) != null && debug(request.auth.uid) == userId;
        allow create: if debug(request) && debug(request.auth) != null;
    }
```

The debug for the `allow create` line is printing out the request, and what's odd is there is a Bearer token in the header (which is missing if I try the same thing when not authenticated) but the auth attribute of the request is null.

```
Apr 16, 2021 6:20:42 PM io.gapi.emulators.netty.HttpVersionRoutingHandler channelRead
INFO: Detected non-HTTP/2 connection.
Apr 16, 2021 6:20:42 PM com.google.net.webchannel.server.common.CorsFilter populateCustomHeaders
WARNING: Invalid $httpHeaders: X-Goog-Api-Client:gl-js/ fire/8.4.1
X-Firebase-GMPID:1:855732088727:web:38fc76872a93ee3e979ed2
Content-Type:text/plain
Authorization:Bearer eyJhbGciOiJub25lIiwidHlwIjoiSldUIn0.eyJwaG9uZV9udW1iZXIiOiIrMTEyMjMzMzU1NTUiLCJhdXRoX3RpbWUiOjE2MTg2MTE2MjYsInVzZXJfaWQiOiJwYmM1bDhjY2E3RUx0d00wS3hjdG45eExlVDJpIiwiZmlyZWJhc2UiOnsiaWRlbnRpdGllcyI6eyJwaG9uZSI6WyIrMTEyMjMzMzU1NTUiXX0sInNpZ25faW5fcHJvdmlkZXIiOiJwaG9uZSJ9LCJpYXQiOjE2MTg2MTE2MjYsImV4cCI6MTYxODYxNTIyNiwiYXVkIjoiZWFybmhhdXMtc3RhZ2luZyIsImlzcyI6Im0dHBzOi8vc2VjdXJldG9rZW4uZ29vZ2xlLmNvbS9lYXJuaGF1cy1zdGFnaW5nIiwic3ViIjoicGJjNWw4Y2NhN0VMdHdNMEt4Y3RuOXhMZVQyaSJ9.

Apr 16, 2021 6:20:42 PM io.gapi.emulators.netty.HttpVersionRoutingHandler channelRead
INFO: Detected non-HTTP/2 connection.
Apr 16, 2021 6:20:42 PM io.gapi.emulators.netty.HttpVersionRoutingHandler channelRead
INFO: Detected non-HTTP/2 connection.
map_value {
  fields {
    key: "auth"
    value {
      null_value: NULL_VALUE
    }
  }
  fields {
    key: "headers"
    value {
      map_value {
      }
    }
  }
  fields {
    key: "inTransaction"
    value {
      bool_value: true
    }
  }
  fields {
    key: "method"
    value {
      string_value: "create"
    }
  }
  fields {
    key: "path"
    value {
      path_value {
        segments {
          simple: "databases"
        }
        segments {
          simple: "(default)"
        }
        segments {
          simple: "documents"
        }
        segments {
          simple: "preferences"
        }
        segments {
          simple: "pbc5l8cca7ELtwM0Kxctn9xLeT2i"
        }
      }
    }
  }
  fields {
    key: "readFields"
    value {
      null_value: NULL_VALUE
    }
  }
  fields {
    key: "resource"
    value {
      map_value {
        fields {
          key: "__name__"
          value {
            path_value {
              segments {
                simple: "databases"
              }
              segments {
                simple: "(default)"
              }
              segments {
                simple: "documents"
              }
              segments {
                simple: "preferences"
              }
              segments {
                simple: "pbc5l8cca7ELtwM0Kxctn9xLeT2i"
              }
            }
          }
        }
        fields {
          key: "data"
          value {
            map_value {
              fields {
                key: "paymentMethod"
                value {
                  string_value: "venmo"
                }
              }
              fields {
                key: "paymentRecipient"
                value {
                  string_value: "+11223335555"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
        fields {
          key: "id"
          value {
            string_value: "pbc5l8cca7ELtwM0Kxctn9xLeT2i"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  fields {
    key: "time"
    value {
      timestamp_value {
        seconds: 1618611642
        nanos: 877000000
      }
    }
  }
  fields {
    key: "transforms"
    value {
      null_value: NULL_VALUE
    }
  }
  fields {
    key: "writeFields"
    value {
      null_value: NULL_VALUE
    }
  }
}

null_value: NULL_VALUE

Apr 16, 2021 6:20:42 PM com.google.cloud.datastore.emulator.impl.util.WrappedStreamObserver onError
INFO: operation failed: 
false for 'create' @ L7
```

The fact that it is null makes it impossible to enforce any security rules.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Which authentication method are you using?

Comment: @Will phone number auth, in the web SDK. I'm able to confirm in the console that `firebase.auth().currentUser` is not null.

Comment: I am encountering identical issue using a custom auth scheme.  Will update you once I figure this out.

Comment: see here – https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/3258